# Group action w.r.t. non-split extension group of the form $2^8\mathbin.(2^7\mathbin:\operatorname{Sp}(6,2))$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I have a non-split extension $2^8\mathbin.(2^7\mathbin:\operatorname{Sp}(6,2))$ of $2^8$ by $2^7\mathbin:\operatorname{Sp}(6,2)$. The question is how does $2^7\mathbin:\operatorname{Sp}(6,2)$ act on $2^8$.  This group sits maximally inside the unique nonsplit extension $2^8\mathbin.\operatorname{Sp}(8,2)$.

Comment: Assuming this is usual Atlas notation, $2^8$ does not act on $(2^7:Sp(6,2))$, since the latter is a quotient, not a normal subgroup.

Comment: Also the title of your post does not agree with the body.

Comment: You might wish to consider the general case of $G.H$ — $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G.H$, so $G.H$ acts by conjugation. From this you can achieve an outer action of $H$.

Comment: Can you explain  "an outer action of H".

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without further information. There is  more than one isomorphism type of group that fits that description.

Comment: @Isaac https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group See also the top of the second page here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bbms/1102715061. See the classic reference https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969174 and the discussion and references at https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Extension_of_a_group

Comment: Where are these various kinds of notations for extensions (the colon and dot, as well as, e.g., whether $2^8$ means, say, the elementary Abelian 2-group of order $2^8$, as I assume, or a cyclic group of order $2^8$, or whatever else) defined?

Comment: @LSpice It's known as the ATLAS notation for group structures defined in the Atlas of Finite Groups. Yes, $2^8$ denotes an elementary abelian group. The cyclic group of that order would be denoted by $256$. You can also use $[256]$ to denote a group of that order with unspecified structure.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, your question makes sense now. The group  $2^7:{\rm Sp}(6,2)$ is a maximal subgroup of ${\rm Sp}(8,2)$, and is the stabilizer of a vector in the action of ${\rm Sp}(8,2)$ on its natural $8$-dimensional module. This immediately defines its action on that module. This action is the same in the split and nonsplit extensions
$2^8:{\rm  Sp}(8,2)$ and $2^8\cdot 
{\rm Sp}(8,2)$.

Comment: So we can then consider $2^8$  as the vector space V(8,2)  where upon  $2^7:$Sp (6,2)  acts as an eight dimensional matrix group over  GF (2). I suppose  this action is not irreducible.

Comment: No, as I said , that subgroup is the stabilizer of a vector. It also stabilizes a $7$-dimensional subspace (which is the space orthogonal to the fixed vector under the symplectic form), and the subgroup ${\rm Sp}(6,2)$ acts in its natural action on the $6$-dimensional quotient of the $7$- by the $1$-dimensional fixed spaces.

Comment: The action of $2^7:Sp (6,2) $ ( constructed  as a 8×8 matrix group within Sp (8,2)) on $2^8$  forms 4 orbits of elements  of $2^8$. I checked it with GAP. What do we call this action?

Comment: I am still waiting on a response  to the last question.